# Limitar tipo de dato "autocomplete"

Tags: php, moodle, autocomplete

Tengo el siguiente código (de Moodle):

```
$searchareas = \core_search\manager::get_search_areas_list(true);
$areanames = array();
foreach ($searchareas as $areaid => $searcharea) {
    $areanames[$areaid] = $searcharea->get_visible_name();
}
$options = array(
    'multiple' => true,
    'noselectionstring' => 'Selecciona hasta tres áreas de conocimiento',
);
$mform->addElement('autocomplete', 'areaids', 'Área de búsqueda', $areanames, $options);
```

Esto me crea un campo de tipo "autocomplete" en el formulario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De la lista, se pueden seleccionar varias opciones:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera limitar este "autocomplete" para que permita seleccionar HASTA TRES datos de la lista, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Hola creo que a lo que te refieres a seleccionar ahí mismo mas de un valor, si si entonces lo puedes hacer de esta forma usando el atributo `multiple`:

```html
<select multiple name="name">
<option>Value</option>
<option>Value</option>
<option>Value</option>
</select>
```

Con **ctrl** click puedes seleccionar los que quieras, si no me explique bien o no es lo que buscabas exactamente, [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/multiple) tienes un link donde explican mejor el uso de `multiple`

Comment: En realidad el código ya tiene el atributo "múltiple" y me permite seleccionar todos los datos que quiera, lo que necesito es que se límite a máximo 3 datos seleccionados

Comment: Entonces creo que [este enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105411/how-to-limit-the-maximum-files-chosen-when-using-multiple-file-input) te puede ayudar